# How to have a close button on the top right corner in nativescript?

Tags: android, ios, vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I want to create my own modal layout with my own close button on the top-right corner.

I have come up with something but it has too many issues, specially on IOS, I will post it but let me just not iterate the problems it has because I'm sure there is a common solution to this that people use and I don't insist on my own implementation, I just want something that behaves as I want.

**Here is my implementation:**

```
<template>
  <ScrollView>
    <GridLayout rows="*" columnts="*,auto">
      <GridLayout 
        row="0"
        col="1"
        opacity=".5"
        @tap="$modal.close"
      >
        <label class="fas" color="white" :text="'fa-circle' | iconmap" />
        <label class="fas" color="black" :text="'fa-times-circle' | iconmap" />
      </GridLayout>
      <StackLayout col="0" row="0">
        <!-- The content of my modal -->
      </StackLayout>
    </GridLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</template>
```

I want it too look as if it was this:

```
<template>
  <ScrollView>
    <StackLayout col="0" row="0">
      <!-- The content of my modal -->
    </StackLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</template>
```

Except that there is a small square on the top-right corner which is above everything(z-index) and if the user clicks on it the modal is closed. I want it to have zero impact on the rest of the page and just independently appear on the top right corner, above everything else.

There are two very common usages for this. one is to have a sticky, button with a fixed position, one would be to have the button scrolled along the content. My implementation is doing the latter but I'm aiming to find a solution for the former here.

Comment: Are you asking how you can reuse the modal with dynamic content every time? Or you are unable to place the button at right position?

Comment: @Manoj I would like to have a scrollable box that has a fixed button on its top right corner. The button should come over the content of the box(z-index) not vertically above it(y axis).

Comment: Use horizontal alignment on button layout not column.

Comment: @Manoj So I put one grid layout with one row and one column. which has two children, one gridlayout which is my button and one scrollview which is the content. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get exactly what I want with [nstudio/nativescript-floatingactionbutton](https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-floatingactionbutton)

`tns plugin add @nstudio/nativescript-floatingactionbutton`

In `main.js`

```
import Vue from 'nativescript-vue';

Vue.registerElement(
  'Fab',
  () => require('@nstudio/nativescript-floatingactionbutton').Fab
);
```

My modal component:

```
<template>
  <GridLayout>
    <VerticalCenterScroll>
      <slot />
    </VerticalCenterScroll>
    <fab @tap="close()" row="1" text="×" rippleColor="#f1f1f1" class="fab-button"/>
  </GridLayout>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      close() {
        if (this.$modal.close) this.$modal.close();
        else $emit('close');
      },
    },
  };
</script>

<style scoped>
  .fab-button {
    height: 50;
    width: 50;
    margin: 15;
    background-color: silver;
    horizontal-align: right;
    vertical-align: top;
    color: black;
  }
</style>
```

You can just use `this.$modal.close()` the function I have is because of certain complexities and frame navigation within some of my modals.

This worked so well. I'm really happy with this great plugin.